# Visual Studio Code - Debugging a spawned process

Tags: node.js, debugging, spawn, visual-studio-code

The project setup, is a basic express application, generated with express-generator.

The project, [vscode-debugging-node](https://github.com/sarbbottam/vscode-debugging-node) is available at GitHub

Please refer the screencast at [Visual studio Code - Debugging node application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcqSFqHbcCc)

---

The [`Gruntfile.js`](https://github.com/sarbbottam/vscode-debugging-node/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) in root of the project, manages the dev process. The purpose of the [`Gruntfile.js`](https://github.com/sarbbottam/vscode-debugging-node/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) is simple, it starts the server and watches for any file changes.
On detecting changes in the desired file(s), it restarts the server (kills the existing process and starts a new one).

The [`Gruntfile.js`](https://github.com/sarbbottam/vscode-debugging-node/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) uses [`./task/server.js`](https://github.com/sarbbottam/vscode-debugging-node/blob/master/task/server.js) to start/restart the server.

The [`Gruntfile.js`](https://github.com/sarbbottam/vscode-debugging-node/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) is developed in this manner, that later on, it will incorporate cookie management, in order to provide a logged in experience.

While executing the `$ grunt start` task, if a `env` variable named `NODE_INSPECTOR=*` is passed, the server is started in [`--debug` mode](https://github.com/sarbbottam/vscode-debugging-node/blob/master/task/server.js#L9-L11).
When the grunt task is executed in `--debug` mode, along with `node-inspector` running in parallel, I can use Chrome to debug the complete application.

---

With reference to [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging), I tried to achieve the same by updating the [`.settings/launch.json`](https://github.com/sarbbottam/vscode-debugging-node/blob/master/.settings/launch.json), with `"program": "/usr/local/bin/grunt"`, `"args": ["start"]` and `"env": {"NODE_INSPECTOR":"*"}`.

I could find that debugger is attached only till `./task/server.js` but on the whole application. I doubt, it may be due to the [`spawn`ed server](https://github.com/sarbbottam/vscode-debugging-node/blob/master/task/server.js#L13).

---

Is this possible to debug such situation in **visual studio code**? If yes, it will be of great help to know the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your doubts are correct, you are configuring Visual Studio Code to attach to the grunt task starting the server, not the server itself.

You have two options to order to debug this:

1. Execute `NODE_INSPECTOR=* grunt start` form the terminal.
   Once the server has started, attach the the running server to the **Debugger**, using the same **Attach** configuration available in `launch.json`.  In the **Debugger** view choose the **Attach** from the profile dropdown and start the **Debugger** (green ► play button).

UPDATE -- 
Sarbbotam recorded a screencast for successfully attaching to his node.js app, you can find it here [Visual studio Code - Attaching a Node App to Debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ql-pUyu83Po)

2. Configure VSCode to run the server directly, for that you won't have the grunt task listening to the changes and restarting the server. In order to do that change the `program` option to `"bin/www"`

Comment: Thanks for your concerns, but thats not what I am looking for, I am aware that I can start the `./bin/www`, but then I loose the flexibility to restart the server on file changes, which is very desirable feature. Using plain node-inspector I can achieve it, please refer the screencast. I am wondering if that would be possible in VS Code.

Comment: Sarbbotam, thanks for the comment, I updated the answer to cover your case, please let me know if this does not work for you.

Comment: Great, highly appreciate your concerns and answers. Yes "Attach" is the option that I had been looking for. It addresses my concerns.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me if it is possible to remote debug, I have updated the `"address"` with `"XX.XX.XXX.XX"`, in `launch.json` . Started the remote server in `--debug` mode. When I try to attach the remote server to the debugger, I get a `connection failed error`. Could you suggest what could be the issue? Is there any log that I can look into, for the detailed issue? I can ssh to my box and also when I execute node-inspector, I am able to access the  node-inspector debugger over http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/debug?ws=XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080&port=5858

Comment: unfortunately remote debugging is not supported yet in VSCode. If that's something you want see, please let us know in User Voice http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code